# Different behavior for window placement only on 2nd showing of windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code that I have simplified to show my issue in my application. I have 2 monitors, and I want a window to display on Monitor 1 and another window on Monitor 2. I have tried all kinds of different methods to determine the correct positions, what I am using is `Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea` and of course `Screen.Allscreens[1]`. In my case, I have the following configuration

```
Monitor 1 - 5120x1440  
Monitor 2 - 2560x1440
```

For Monitor 1 it returns the following Rectangle

```
Left 0  
Top 0  
Width 5120  
Height 1392
```

For Monitor 2 it returns the following Rectangle (because scaling is 125% and is offset in the display settings)

```
Left 5120  
Top 353  
Width 2048  
Height 1104
```

The problem that I have is the first time that I show the windows, it places them properly like they are supposed to be, one on each monitor, full size of the working area.

The 2nd time though, Window 2 is placed in the same Top/Left as Window 1 even though I have specified it not to.

The kicker - each and every time after that, Window 2 is put in its correct position!!!

Things I have tried:
All different kinds of properties for the windows themselves.
Note, in my code, it is called from `Task.Run(Current.Dispatcher.Invoke...` but I wanted to simplify it.
Putting a sleep in between showing the 2 windows.
Changing the scaling of the 2nd monitor to 100%
Aligning the 2 monitors so that the Top is 0 on monitor 2
Setting the left and top again after calling `Show()`
Calling `windowN.Focus()` prior to show to make sure it has the focus
Showing `window2` before `window1`
Added Top/Left/Width/Height as labels on the Window and confirmed that something is setting the position of `window2` to Top = 0, Left = 0
Changed DPI and resolution to be the same on both monitors

Here is just a basic WPF C# application demonstrating the issue

`MainWindow.xaml` - No change in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="ABCD" Foreground="Red" FontSize="36" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App.xaml - removed StartupUri from base project template

```xml
<Application x:Class="TestApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And finally the code - here I have hardcoded the value to remove any doubt about `Screen.WorkingArea` returning different values.

```
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {
        MainWindow window1 = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow window2 = new MainWindow();

        private IKeyboardMouseEvents keyboardMouseEvents = Hook.GlobalEvents();

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            keyboardMouseEvents.KeyUp += KeyboardMouseEvents_KeyUp;

            window1.Title = "WINDOW 1";
            window2.Title = "WINDOW 2";
        }

        private void KeyboardMouseEvents_KeyUp(object? sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LControlKey)
            {
                Toggle();
            }
        }

        private void Show()
        {
            window1.Left = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Left;
            window1.Top = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Top;
            window1.Width = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Width;
            window1.Height = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Height;
            window1.Show();

            window2.Left = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Left;
            window2.Top = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Top;
            window2.Width = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Width;
            window2.Height = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Left {window2.Left} Top {window2.Top} Width {window2.Width} Height {window2.Height}");
            window2.Show();

        }

        private void Toggle()
        {
            if (window1.IsVisible)
            {
                window1.Hide();
                window2.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the 2nd call for my code, here it is putting Window2 at 0, 0 even though I told it a different value (see debug output after screenshot)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where does Gma.System.MouseKeyHook namespace come from?

Comment: Ok, found MouseKeyHook Nuget package. Where do you initially show the window?

Comment: At the same coordinates I put in there, the left, top, width and height.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by initially. I removed StartupUri from App.xaml so no window is shown initially.

Comment: Right, use left control key, lol - you have to admit, it's a weird application! Ok I had to change my width and height on the two windows to 2560 and 1410 (your example would be better if you used the numbers from the WorkingArea property :)). The windows are placed as expected every time for me (:

Comment: Sorry, I tried to keep the sample as minimal yet close to my app as possible. I didn't want another UI with a button to toggle it in case it changes the window behavior.

Comment: @JimFoye what version of windows are you on, and what net framework did you use? Maybe there is a difference where it would work for you and not for me.

Comment: I created the app in Windows 10 using VS 2019, targeted 4.7.2.

Comment: I updated my code and added some screenshots. I am on Windows 11 so possibly a change between the two. I will see about using 4.7.2

Comment: So yes, it works fine in 4.7.2. I was using NET 7.0. Possibly a bug :(

Comment: I haven't moved any of my WPF apps over to .NET Core - too many problems.